# Render Partial View using Jquery Ajax with variable data

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery, renderpartial

I have already read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1570127/render-partial-view-using-jquery-in-asp-net-mvc), but I am not sure know to make it work taking data from the user. Here is the ajax jquery I am using. I know (or at least think) that this cant render a partial. But it works all the way until the render fails. I thought it may be helpful to have.

```
 $.ajax(
     {
         type: 'POST',
         contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
         data: "{'test':" + "'" + dateText + "'}",
         dataType: 'json',
         url: 'Site/Grab/',
         success: function (result) {
         alert('Success');
         },

         error: function (error) {
            alert('Fail');
         }
      });
```

Here is my controller

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Grab(string test)
    {
        DateTime lineDate= Convert.ToDateTime(test);
        List<Info> myInfo= GameCache.Data(lineDate);
       return PartialView("_PartialView", myInfo);
    }
```

Comment: If it works until it tries rendering the partial, the problem is most likely in the partial view's markup. Please provide that code, as well as the error you're receiving.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Okay, couple of things to try:

1) `dataType` is the expected result of the ajax call. In your case, your **sending** JSON, but **receiving** HTML. The `content-type` parameter specifies the request, which you have (and what you have is correct). So the data type should be:

```
dataType: 'html',
```

2) You need to serialize the JSON. Try grabbing the lightweight **[JSON](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js)** library and **stringify**'ing:

```
var test = { test: 'testvalue' };
$.ajax {
   ...
   data: JSON.stringify(test),
   ...
});
```

Much easier than trying to coerce a JSON string with quoatations. Create a regular JS variable, then stringify it.

The rest of your code looks fine.

If it's a problem with the HTML/markup of the partial view itself, run in debug mode and Visual Studio should stop on the line in the markup that is causing the problem.

**Bonus Hint**: ASP.NET MVC 3 includes built-in JSON model binding. So you can create a basic POCO that matches the fields of your JSON object, then accept it as a strongly-typed object in the action method:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Grab(MyJsonObject obj) 
{
   DateTime lineDate= Convert.ToDateTime(obj.test);
   List<Info> myInfo= GameCache.Data(lineDate);
   return PartialView("_PartialView", myInfo);
}
```

Since your only sending one parameter, it's overkill - but if you have more than 2 then it's worthwhile using a JSON POCO.

Comment: when I switched data data type to html is repaired the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Change your controller code to:

```
public ActionResult Grab(string test) {
  DateTime lineDate= Convert.ToDateTime(test);
  List<Info> myInfo= GameCache.Data(lineDate);

  return Json(new { data = this.RenderPartialViewToString("_PartialView", myInfo) });
}
```

Comment: where the "RenderPartialViewToString()" method exists?

Comment: Here http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/7150/implementing-renderpartialviewtostring-in-asp-net-mvc-3.aspx or here http://craftycodeblog.com/2010/05/15/asp-net-mvc-render-partial-view-to-string/