# render partial view to string

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, partial-views

I have a login form that is shown on all pages of my mvc site asking the user to login or shows them a welcome message if they are already logged in along with various account details (company logo etc), I do not have a login page itself all login is handled via this 'widget'

To implement this I have the following so far

In my main layout

```
<div id="top_right">
    @{ Html.Partial("_LogOnPartial");}
</div>
```

_LogOnPartial.cshtml

```
@if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
{
    // TODO: show company logo
    Html.RenderAction("Details", "Account");

}
else
{
    Html.RenderAction("LogOn", "Account");
}
```

Account controller

```
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    public PartialViewResult LogOn()
    {
        return PartialView();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult LogOn(LogOnModel userDetails, string returnUrl)
    {
        //TODO: validate user here

        if(ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if(Membership.ValidateUser(userDetails.UserName, userDetails.Password))
            {
                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(userDetails.UserName, userDetails.RememberMe);

                return Redirect(returnUrl);
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "The username or password provided was incorrect");
            }
        }

        return PartialView(userDetails);

    }

    public PartialViewResult Details()
    {
        //TODO: query membership for user information

        var user = new UserDetailsViewModel();


        return PartialView(user);
    }
}
```

}

LogOn.cshtml

```
@model LogOnModel

 <div id="login">
        @Html.ValidationSummary()

        <h2>Start by Loggin in</h2>

        @using (Html.BeginForm("LogOn", "Account"))
        {
            @Html.Hidden("returnUrl", Request.Url.PathAndQuery)

            <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <span class="bluey">Username:</span><br />
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName,new {tabindex="1", Class = "field"})
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.UserName, "*")
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <span class="bluey">Password:</span><br />
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Password, new {tabindex = "2", Class="field"})
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m=> m.Password, "*")
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input name="login" type="submit" value="Submit" class="input_btn" tabindex="3" />
                    </td>
                    <td>@Html.CheckBoxFor(m=>m.RememberMe) @Html.LabelFor(m=> m.RememberMe) <span class="bluey">&nbsp; | &nbsp;</span> @Html.ActionLink("Forgot Password?", "Password", "User")></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        }
    </div>
```

I've read a few posts and it would appear I will need to change my LogOn.cshtml to use jquery to do a post do the /Account/LogOn action method and then update the the html of the div success or failure.

I've seen it done with a custom [RenderPartialViewToString](http://craftycodeblog.com/2010/05/15/asp-net-mvc-render-partial-view-to-string/) but someone also recommended that returning the [Partial](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1570138/351614) from the Action was enough and this would be processed correctly via the jquery code, replacing the div (or whatever element) with the new html.

I also saw an example returning Json(model) but I'm not sure if that would return the actual view or just the model data encoded as json

Are both of these approaches viable or is there a better way to do this?