# How to design a form that collects different type of data but other fields are the same

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database, forms

I am designing an asset management where I am tracking things like software, monitors, and workstations, etc. As you can see, these assets have different data attributes and having a form that collects data from them is my question. I have designed one table to hold all attributes where some fields will be empty due to the fact that each asset type has different features from another type. I am designing a web-based solution in .Net and I am wondering how I can design a form to show fields depending on the asset type selected by the user. Thanks for your help.

What I have is a drop-down that has the type and one a type is selected, relevant fields to the type are shown and will be validated upon submitting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest these steps:

1. Create one partial view per asset type.
2. Add a div to your main view(where your have drop-down)
3. In drop-down's click event, make a Ajax call to load respective partial view into the div added in step 2.

Note: partial view in your case should not have submit button, all submits should go through the main view.

check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1570127/render-partial-view-using-jquery-in-asp-net-mvc) to see how to load partial view into a div

Good luck.

Comment: This is really excellent. One question I have to ponder upon now is validation and inserting in the database. Any suggestions would be highly appreciated. Thanks.