# How this page is composed to do it with MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-ajax

Let me clarify you that I'm a newbie using `MVC4` and `AJAX`.

Please see the below image, contains two main views (the rectangles with `background-color=white`
[image]

In the left section, it has a question list for a test and the right is something like a question editor view.

I need to implement something similiar. My big doubt is how to start implementing these interface? I mean I supposed these are two partial vies or editor templates, and how are they interacting I mean, when I press the button `NEW QUESTION`, add a question to the list and show the question detail in the second one. I supposed when press the `DONE` button, sends a post to the server with the questions created, something like this:

```
public ActionResult Done(List<Question> questions)
{

}
```

I guess this can be accomplished through `AJAX`.

I'm not asking for code, I just want some explanation about how to create the interaction in the web page, I'm really get lost.

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to call your controller from jQuery, check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1570138/1015010