# How do I render a partial site to another div?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I want a view with a table on the site and when you click on a table Item, i want to update a partial view with the current object I just clicked on. How do I manage to do this?

```
<table>
    @foreach (var a in annotations)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label onclick="change stuff to new Annotation">@a.Title</label>
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
<div id="stuff">@Html.RenderPartial("Go", "new annotation")"</div>
```

Comment: I just changed the example into a newer one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're mixing client-side and server-side code.  By the time the click event occurs, you're on the client and server-side code has run and finished.

You could render the partial view in a hidden `div` and just unhide it on the click event.  Something similar to this, perhaps:

```
<table>
@foreach (var a in annotations)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label>@a.Title</label>
            <div style="display:none;">@Html.RenderPartial("Go", a)</div>
        </td>
    </tr>
}
</table>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('table tr td label').click(function () {
            $(this).closest('td').find('div').show();
        });
    });
</script>
```

There may be a more elegant way to find the correct `div` in the jQuery selectors, you can perhaps add classes and ids to DOM elements as needed to make it cleaner.  If you have a lot of these table rows then I'd also recommend using the jQuery `.on()` function for binding the click event as it would perform better.  Something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('body').on('click', 'table tr td label', function () {
            $(this).closest('td').find('div').show();
        });
    });
</script>
```

This would bind a single click event to the DOM instead of many, with the added bonus that dynamically added rows would still handle the event after the binding takes place.

Comment: Well this might work, but I don't want to execute the @Html.RenderPartial all the times when I create the table, it could be huge and it would eat up my performance. Is there some way that i can run it just when i click on it?

Comment: @Tartori: Ah, I see you recently changed the question.  That does change things a bit, yes.  A little digging found a nice solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1570127/render-partial-view-using-jquery-in-asp-net-mvc  It basically uses AJAX to get the partial view and then renders it to the page.  In either case you're going to have to make sure you keep a clean separation of server-side and client-side code.

Comment: OK thanks, yeah, I added the newer example, saw just that I used something i just tried out...

Answer (score 0):

your getting your client side and server side code mixed up here.

```
@Html.RenderPartial("Go", a)
```

is a server side method that returns some HTML.

```
<label onclick=
```

Is client side code. So by the time your client gets the data it looks like this:

```
<label onclick="The text returned from html.render partial">
```

I think you need to read up on MVC a bit more to achieve what you want as your fundamentally going down the wrong route here.