# how to pass parameter to partial view in MVC4 razor

Tags: jquery, view, partial, parameterized

In my asp.net mvc 4 application i want to pass a parameter to partial view,however the parameter we want to pass is coming from javascript code

Below is the code

```
<script>
    var TestId;

 $(document).ready(function () {

        // Send an AJAX request       


        $.getJSON("/api//GetFun?Id="+@ViewBag.Id,

                function (data) {

TestId= data.Id
//i am getting the id here which i need to pass in partial view

}
1)...........
});


</script>
```

html code:

```
 <div id="tab1" >

 2)....      @{ Html.RenderAction("MyPartialView", "MyController", new { id = TestId });}
  </div>
```

So let me know how can i pass the test id to my partial view :in HTML(2) code or in javascript (1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the below code in your javascript and Load your view from javascript function

```
var url = '@Url.Action("MyPartialView", "MyController")';
url += '/?Id=' + TestId ;
$("#tab1").load(url);
```

Put the below Code in your Controller

```
public ActionResult MyPartialView( int id )
{
    return Partial( "MyPartialView", id );
}
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1570127/render-partial-view-using-jquery-in-asp-net-mvc) SO question:

Assuming your controller is called "MyController", your partial view is called "MyPartialView", and you create a controller method that accepts the Id parameter and returns the partial view:

```
public ActionResult GetPartialView( int id )
{
    return Partial( "MyPartialView", id );
}
```

You could then load the partial view using the below jQuery:

```
$('#tab1').load('/My/GetPartialView?id=' + TestId);
```

Answer (score 0):

**View:** At here we pass *"category"* parameter to the Controller with *"admin"* value

```
@{ Html.RenderAction("Menu", "Nav", new { category = "admin" }); }
```

**Controller:** At here we get *"category"* parameter's value

```
public PartialViewResult Menu(string category, string menu = null)
{
     IEnumerable<Menu> menus = repository.Menus
    .Select(x => x)
    .Where(x => (x.MenuCategory == category)
    .OrderBy(x => x.MenuSequence).ToList(); 
     return PartialView(menus);
}
```

Hope this helps.