# jQuery - dynamically loading ASP.NET partial view into modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc-4

**Question background:**

I have an MVC project where I am attempting to create a partial view `modal` content that is then concatenated to the rest of its respective `modal` markup and then finally appending to a 'main' `modal` div.

**The code**:

Main modal div:

```
<div class="modal fade" 
     id="basicModal" 
     tabindex="-1" 
     role="dialog" 
     aria-labelledby="basicModal" 
     aria-hidden="true">
</div>
```

JQuery to trigger the modal popup along with the `AddModal` method to build the modal content:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".btn").click(function () {

        AddModal();

        $("#basicModal").modal("show");
    });
});
</script>
```

`AddModal` method to build the modal:

```
AddModal = function() {

var partialHtml = $(@Html.Partial("../Modal/Index", new { id = 1 }))

    $html = $('<div class="modal-dialog">' +
    '<div class="modal-content">' +
        '<div class="modal-header">' +
            '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">X</button>' +
            '<h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>' +
        '</div>' +
        '<div class="modal-body">'+partialHtml+'</div>' +
        '<div class="modal-footer">' +
            '<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>' +
            '<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>' +
        '</div>' +
    '</div>' +
    '</div>');

    $("#basicModal").append($html);
};
```

Partial View:

```
<h4>Test Partial view</h4>
```

**The issue:**

I am running into an error of `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <` which is being caused by the HTML Markup of the partial view as shown:

```
var partialHtml = $(<h4>Test Partial view</h4>)
```

How can I successfully escape this forward slash so that the HTML from my partial view is correctly added to the rest of the dynamically added markup?

Comment: try use quotes like `$('@Html.Partial("../Modal/Index", new { id = 1 })')`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using `Html.Partial()` and storing that in a JavaScript string, consider using this technique: [Render Partial View Using jQuery in ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1570138/3191599)

Basically, in your `AddModal()` method, fire off a GET request that hits an action that returns the partial view as HTML. Then, just replace the contents of `#basicModal` with the returned HTML:

```
AddModal = function() {
    var partialHtml;
    var url = '../Modal/Index?id=1';

    $.get(url, function(data) {
        $("#basicModal").html(data);
    });
};
```

I've used this technique to load modals before and it works well. However, one problem with doing it this way is that `$.get()` is an **async** call, so `.modal("show")` is probably going to fire before the data has been fetched. We can solve this by having `AddModal` return the promise generated by `$.get()`:

```
AddModal = function() {
    var partialHtml;
    var url = '../Modal/Index?id=1';

    return $.get(url, function(data) {
        $("#basicModal").html(data);
    });
};
```

Then you would change your calling line to:

```
AddModal().done(function() {
    $("#basicModal").modal("show");
});
```

Comment: Fantastic example thank you. The only issue I had was I needed to replace `.replaceWith` with `append`. Failing to do this was causing my modal popup to appear behind the backdrop. Many thanks!

Comment: Cheers. It was early and my brain wasn't working fully. `.html()` should be the call, since this will replace any existing content with the new content you grabbed.