# How to refresh mvc webgrid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, refresh, webgrid, page-numbering

I am using a WebGrid in my mvc application.

```
<div class="grid-div" id="webgridid">
                @grid.GetHtml(
    tableStyle: "gridTable",
    headerStyle: "gridHead",
    footerStyle: "gridFooter",
    columns: new[]
    {
        grid.Column("name","Name", canSort: true, style: "name"),
        grid.Column("description","Description", canSort: true, style: "description"),
        grid.Column("duration","Duration", canSort: true, style: "duration"),
   })
</div>
```

I can edit the selected row values using a form. After editing this values, it is not reflecting in my webGrid. But it is reflecting in DataBase. To reflect this in to the webGrid, I need to refresh the webGrid by loading datas from DB. How can I reload contents to webGrid from DB? Also after reloading it, this pageNumber should the old one. How to do this?

Comment: Have you looked at using a partial and calling an action with ajax jquery. [Example here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1570127/render-partial-view-using-jquery-in-asp-net-mvc)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally I find the solution for my problem. I have to define a `<div>` with `ID` and refer the `div`’s `id` in the `ajaxUpdateContainerId` attribute of `WebGrid` control that will allow `WebGrid` to update data asynchronously using `Ajax`.

```
<div id="ajaxgrid">
  @{
      var grid = new WebGrid(Model, rowsPerPage: 10, selectionFieldName: "SelectedRow", ajaxUpdateContainerId: "ajaxgrid");                   
   }
</div>
```

Then, call the `GetHtml` method of `WebGrid`, so that Razor Engine can generate corresponding `HTML` for it. After the end of `<div>` tag.

```
@grid.GetHtml(
    tableStyle: "gridTable",
    headerStyle: "gridHead",
    footerStyle: "gridFooter",
    columns: new[]
    {
        grid.Column("name","Name", canSort: true, style: "name"),
        grid.Column("description","Description", canSort: true, style: "description"),
        grid.Column("duration","Duration", canSort: true, style: "duration"),
   })
```

Then in my `ajax` call for updation I have added `location.reload()` to refresh my `WebGrid`.

```
$.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("User", "UserDetails")',
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                data: formData,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                success: function (result) {
                    if (result == "OK") {
                        location.reload();
                    }
                    else
                        alert(result);
                },
                error: function (result) {
                    alert('Error!');
                }
            });
```

Now its working fine for me.

Comment: Thanks for this! location.reload(); was all I needed to get working what I needed!

Comment: @itzmebibin I believe using a partial view or $('#Grid').append(...) in Jquery, would be more appropriate for what you are expecting. Rather than refreshing the whole page.