# How to use RadioButton to render View

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a controller as shown below.

```
        public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(db.FEE_TYPES.ToList());
    }
```

By default it will render a View called Index. However, I have three views I want to Render

1. Index
2. Index2
3. Index3

I want to have three RadioButtons on the View

1. RadioButton1
2. RadioButton2
3. RadioButton3

When RadioButton1 is clicked, Render Index.
When RadioButton2 is clicked, Render Index2
When RadioButton3 is clicked, Render Index3

Please how do I achieve this?

Comment: you can use combination of `jquery ajax` and `mvc partial view` to achieve this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1570127/render-partial-view-using-jquery-in-asp-net-mvc) `onchange` of radiobutton make an ajax call and render partial view accordingly

Comment: `$.ajax` callback & `Html.RenderPartial` on its `success` part should suffice,with `return PartialView` instead of `View`. You can handle `$('#radiobuttonid').change(...)` event handler to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have Created a Demo from your Code Reference.

First i have create a Model with 3 properties in it.

> **Model**

```
public class DemoModel
{
    public string Radio1 { get; set; }
    public string Radio2 { get; set; }
    public string Radio3 { get; set; }
}
```

After creating a Model i have created a Controller with name RadioRenderController in that controller i have added 4 Action Method in that Index returns Main View.

And Remaining 3 Action Methods [ GetView1 , GetView2 , GetView3 ] return partial View.

> **Controller**

```
using System.Web.Mvc;
using WebApplication6.Models;

namespace WebApplication6.Controllers
{
    public class RadioRenderController : Controller
    {
        // GET: RadioRender
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            DemoModel DemoModel = new Models.DemoModel();
            return View(DemoModel);
        }

        public ActionResult GetView1()
        {
            return PartialView("_DemoView1");
        }

        public ActionResult GetView2()
        {
            return PartialView("_DemoView2");
        }

        public ActionResult GetView3()
        {
            return PartialView("_DemoView3");
        }
    }
}
```

> **View**

```
@model WebApplication6.Models.DemoModel
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index</title>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function GetView1() {
            $("#viewPlaceHolder").load("/RadioRender/GetView1");
        }
        function GetView2() {
            $("#viewPlaceHolder").load("/RadioRender/GetView2");
        }
        function GetView3() {
            $("#viewPlaceHolder").load("/RadioRender/GetView3");
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Radio1, "1", new { @onclick = "GetView1();" }) Radio1
    </div>
    <div>
        @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Radio1, "2", new { @onclick = "GetView2();" }) Radio2
    </div>
    <div>
        @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Radio1, "3", new { @onclick = "GetView3();" }) Radio3
    </div>
    <div id="viewPlaceHolder"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

> **Partial Views**

[image: Partial Views]

> **Output**

[image]