# Loading a partial view in mvc using JQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to add a partial view to my layout using [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1570127/render-partial-view-using-jquery-in-asp-net-mvc).

I have the following relevant code:

**ShowStatistics.cshtml**

```
 <script src="/scripts/jquery-3.3.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>


$(document).ready(function () {
        $('.jsload').on('click', function (evt) {
                evt.preventDefault();
                evt.stopPropagation();

            var $detailDiv = $('#detailsDiv'),
                url = $(this).data('url');

            $.get(url, function (data) {
                $detailDiv.replaceWith(data);
            });
        });
})
</script>

<div id="detailsDiv">
            <!--Content gets loaded by JQuery-->
</div>
        <button data-url='@Url.Action("Details","Statistics", new { id = Model.Id } )' class="jsload">
            Show Skills
        </button>
```

**PlayerSkills.cshtml**

```
@model MVC.Models.ViewPlayerSkills
@{
    Layout = null;
}
<p>HAHAHAHAHAHAHHAHAHAHHAHAHAHAHHAH</p>
@foreach (var property in ViewData.ModelMetadata.Properties)
{
    <div class="editor">
        <label>@(property.DisplayName ?? property.PropertyName):</label>
        @Html.Display(property.PropertyName)
    </div>
}
```

**StatisticsController.cs**

```
        public ActionResult Details(int id)
    {
        List<Player> allPlayers = GetPlayers();
        Player pl = allPlayers.Where(x => x.Id == id).FirstOrDefault();
        ViewPlayerSkills player = new ViewPlayerSkills(pl);
        return PartialView("PlayerSkills", player);

    }
```

I'm getting the following error message:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: data is not defined
>       at Object.success (3:21)
>       at fire (jquery-3.3.1.js:3268)
>       at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-3.3.1.js:3398)
>       at done (jquery-3.3.1.js:9305)
>       at XMLHttpRequest. (jquery-3.3.1.js:9548) (anonymous) @ 3:21 fire @ jquery-3.3.1.js:3268 fireWith @ jquery-3.3.1.js:3398 done
>   @ jquery-3.3.1.js:9305 (anonymous) @ jquery-3.3.1.js:9548 load (async)
>   send @ jquery-3.3.1.js:9567 ajax @ jquery-3.3.1.js:9206
>   jQuery.(anonymous function) @ jquery-3.3.1.js:9355 (anonymous) @ 3:20
>   dispatch @ jquery-3.3.1.js:5183 elemData.handle @ jquery-3.3.1.js:4991

When I go to the url http://localhost:{port}/Statistics/Details/5

I do get my desired output:

[image: Output]

Comment: You need to wrap the script in `$(document).ready()` or move the script to the bottom of the page (you are adding a handler to a DOM element that does not yet exist)

Comment: @StephenMuecke ah yes you're right, now I do get an error message let me change my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script src="/scripts/jquery-3.3.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.jsload').on('click', function (evt) {
            evt.preventDefault();
            evt.stopPropagation();;
            $('#detailsDiv').load($(this).data('url'));
        });
    })
</script>
<div id="detailsDiv">
    <!--Content gets loaded by JQuery-->
</div>
<button data-url='@Url.Action("Details","Statistics", new { id = Model.Id } 
)' class="jsload">
  Show Skills
</button>
```