# How to load partial view from JQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

After $.post it works ,but how do I load partial view here?

```
$.post(url, { sypplyerName: sName, PerTranChallanId: pChallanId, ChalPerchesTranCode: pTranCodeINCHAL, ChallaNo: challaNo, TaxAmount: taxAmount, TotalAmount: totalAmount }, function (json) {
  $.notify("Update And Convert Challan Succesfully ", "success");

  alert("OKKKKKKKKKKKK")
  // From Here I want to load partial view 
  $.json("/Shared/PerchesChallan", function (respnse) {

    $.show(@Html.Partial("PerchesChallan")).html();
    return false
  });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

To load a partial view, you need to create an **Action** on your **Controller** that will return the rendered result.

Then use this code

```
$('#ContainerToLoad').load('@Url.Action("ActionName", "ControllerName")');
```

instead of

```
$.show(@Html.Partial("PerchesChallan")).html();
```

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17239432/3835843) also help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can load a partial view (which has a controller action returning a PartialView response) like so:

The 'parent' view:

```
<div id="partial-panel"></div>

<script>
    ...
    $.post("/mycontroller/_myview", data, function(response) {
        $("#partial-panel").html(response);
    });
    ...
</script>
```

The 'mycontroller' Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult _MyView([your params here]) {
   //..do stuff

   return PartialView();
}
```

The Partial View for `_MyView` will just have your content in it.