# jquery replacewith() strip out javascript

Tags: jquery

This is what I have tried:

```
$("#container").replaceWith('<div>Hello</div><script>console.log(a);</script>')
```

the final result will have no script tag.

for clarity :

**replaceWith(content),the content was returned from server ,through ajax.**

the javascript has been stripped out,feature or bug?

Comment: see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/730916/whats-the-difference-between-jquerys-replacewith-and-html

Comment: thanks for the answer,but it seems can not solve the problem,when the content mixed with script and html

Answer (score 0):

Why would you do that? You already are in JavaScript code. Just do this:

```
$('#container').replaceWith('<div>Hello</div>');
console.log(a);
```

Comment: The content is returned from server throught ajax.and you don't know what the script is .so your answer is not proper.I should describe my question more accurate.