# JQuery replaceWith() does not work onChange

Tags: jquery, ajax

im using this code to replace `<div id="replaceit"></div>` with content in my dynamic url
but it does not instant update when i change select option.

how can i make it work.

Thank you!

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function updatePreview() {
        var year = $("#year").val();
        var month = $("#month").val();
        var dynamicUrl = "print.php?year=" + year + "&month=" + month;

        $.get(dynamicUrl, function(data) {
            $("#replaceit").replaceWith(data);
        }).fail(function() {
            alert("Failed to fetch preview content. Please try again.");
        });
    }

    $('#year, #month').on('change', function(){
        updatePreview();
    });
    updatePreview();

});
```

Comment: Please include the relevant HTML and a sample of the output of your ajax call.  See [mcve].  The existing answers at this time make assumptions regarding the ajax call result.

Comment: Please clarify *"does not **instant** update"* - does it update, but takes a long time?  does it update once, but not a second/third time?  Are there errors in your console?  Does the network tab show the request and the response?  Are these as expected?

Comment: See [what's the difference between replaceWith() and html()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/730916/whats-the-difference-between-jquerys-replacewith-and-html) - `$("#replaceit")` will remove `#replaceit`, unless `data` includes a replacement `replaceit`.  As you call `updatePreview()` once, the subsequent calls to updatePreview() from the `select` change event *probably* won't work.

Answer (score 1):

**Try Like this**

**STEP 1 : set the HTML like this**

```
 <div id="replace">  // if you have not any parent div of #replaceit
    <div id="replaceit">

    </div>
</div>
```

**STEP 2 : Replace your JavaScript code with the following code**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function updatePreview(digit) {
        var year = $("#year").val();
        var month = $("#month").val();
        var dynamicUrl = "print.php?year=" + year + "&month=" + month;

        if(digit == 2){
          $('#replace').html('<div id="replaceit"></div>');  // You can target by any parent div (id) if you dont want to create new div (#replace).
        }
        
        $.get(dynamicUrl, function(data) {
            $("#replaceit").replaceWith(data);
        }).fail(function() {
            alert("Failed to fetch preview content. Please try again.");
        });
    }

    $('#year, #month').on('change', function(){
        updatePreview(2);
    });
    updatePreview(1);

});
```

Comment: Seems overkill for otherwise simply changing to `$("#replaceit").html(data)`

Answer (score 0):

`replaceWith` removes the selected elements from the dom. I think yuo want to replace the contents of the element, to do this use `.html()`

```
$("#replaceit").html(data);
```

Comment: hi, i want to use replaceWith because im planning to print my page without <div id="replaceit"></div>

Comment: If you use `replaceWith` the function `updatePreview` will only be able to work once, your change event will have to element to fill with data.

Comment: To clarify the "*removes the selected elements*" and "*will only work once*" - see [what's the difference between replaceWith() and html()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/730916/whats-the-difference-between-jquerys-replacewith-and-html) - `$("#replaceit")` will remove `#replaceit`, unless `data` includes a replacement `replaceit`

Comment: *I want to use replaceWith because* - then you can only "replace it" once.  If you don't want to print something, then exclude it using css:  `@media print { #replaceit { display:none; } }`